# swing - Triggering Tree Cell Edit Event

Tags: java, swing, editor, rename, jtree

I have a JTree with editable nodes.

How can I programmatically trigger the tree cell edit event, i.e. bring up the node-renaming textbox in place of a highlighted node, as if the user manually highlighted it and pressed F2?

Basically I want to add a "Rename" menu item or toolbar button, to clue users in on that particular function of the tree, and I want it to function identically to an F2 keypress when the user highlights a node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) some node is selected (by `Mouse` / `KeyBoard` event) and by listening by  `TreeSelectionListener`, then selected path has unique ID

2) add `Swing Action` to `JMenuItem` (in `JPopup`???, not clear from your question, how to get node from /to ???)

3) create class, void, whatever and to fire

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
    public void run() {  
        tree.startEditingAtPath(path);  
    }  
});
```

4) based on answer by [`@Michael Dunn`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938650/michael-dunn) to my  [question on another forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/584508/GUI/java/change-DefaultCellEditor-setClickCountToStart-int-DefaultTreeCellEditor)

Comment: 3 did it. That was what I was looking for; somehow I couldn't find it after trawling through the javadoc. -_- Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic)

> To make the text in the tree's nodes editable, we invoke
> setEditable(true) on the tree. When the user has finished editing a
> node, the model generates a tree model event that tells any listeners
> — including the JTree — that tree nodes have changed. Note that
> although DefaultMutableTreeNode has methods for changing a node's
> content, changes should go through the DefaultTreeModel cover methods.
> Otherwise, the tree model events would not be generated, and listeners
> such as the tree would not know about the updates.

EDIT:

To add a context menu for a node, see this question: [Right-click context menu for Java JTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517704/right-click-context-menu-for-java-jtree).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that wasn't really what I was asking. Admittedly I wasn't very clear. No matter, it's answered now. :)

Comment: what if I dont want the entire path to be displayed for renaming, I need only the Leaf node's name to be displayed